# Integration of Design Studio (version 1.5) with External/SAPUI5 Application (version 1.28.7)

Tags: sapui5, business-objects, hana

I want to know the best way to integrate a SAP Design Studio BIP application to a SAPUI5 application.

My scenario in detail is:

My client has humongous amount of data, some millions of records at the most granular level. They cannot display all that data in a Design Studio application so they are using the hybrid path of creating a few pages/views like dashboards in SAP Design Studio and then navigating to a SAPUI5 view to display the most granular level data exposed via HANA XS OData service.

**Solution Setup**:
Both the applications are on different servers. The Design Studio application is on BO server while the SAPUI5 application is on HANA Server. This is so because the Design Studio on HANA has various limitations (which client says and i am not aware of).

**Current Solution**:
We have been successfully able to launch the SAPUI5 application from Design Studio views via calling the URL of the SAPUI5 application and then passing the context as URL parameters. Then parsing the parameters and using them in SAPUI5 application.

**Current Challenges**:

1. How will the authentication work because now we are entering the credentials separately for every server. Should it be SSO enabled. (and may not work with mobile devices)
2. Session Time-out issues like a user may have been logged out from Design Studio but the SAPUI5 application with data is already opened in new tab, then should the data be still available or on refresh, it should prompt for login.
3. Is navigation as done via calling an external URL the best way or do we have some other better option?